# Issues with regular expression and Named Reference

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
"1     Compensation for the month Jan,2020                 10                 160                       1600"
```

I would like to split the string into multiple groups using "Named Regular expression". I would like to split into the following groups:

```
'Index' : 1
'Description': 'Compensation for the month Jan,2020'
'HourlyRate': '10'
'TotalHours': '160'
'Total': '1600'
```

I used the following Regular expression:

```
(?P<Index>\w+)\s+(?P<Description>\w+)\s+(?P<HourlyRate>.+)\s+(?P<TotalHours>.+)\s+(?P<Total>)
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may leverage the fact that the first and last three fields are number fields, thus, in the second field, you may match any amount of any chars:

```
^(?P<Index>\d+)\s+(?P<Description>.*?)\s+(?P<HourlyRate>\d+)\s+(?P<TotalHours>\d+)\s+(?P<Total>\d+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fMhb7r/1). If the numbers can have fractional parts, replace that `\d+` pattern with `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` (or `\d+(?:,\d+)?` if you have a comma as a decimal separator).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?P<Index>\d+)` - 1+ digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?P<Description>.*?)` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?P<HourlyRate>\d+)` - 1+ digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?P<TotalHours>\d+)` - 1+ digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?P<Total>\d+)` - 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: This did work. I had to expand the search to include "-" if the entry is empty.